# Angular 2 Setup Issues

Tags: angular, npm, typescript-typings

On the front-end I want to use Angular 2 with Node.js and TypeScript and on the back-end I want to use Java. I am trying to set up the UI application with Angular 2 and NPM after I got an example application working.

However, the NPM is throwing a bunch of errors coming from common packages.
[image]

Here is my tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Here is my typings.json:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "bluebird": "registry:npm/bluebird#3.5.0+20170314181206",
    "debug": "registry:npm/debug#2.0.0+20170504163145"
  },
  "globalDependencies": {
    "atom": "registry:env/atom#1.6.0+20160723033700",
    "d3": "github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/d3/d3.d.ts#1c05872e7811235f43780b8b596bfd26fe8e7760",
    "mocha": "registry:dt/mocha#2.2.5+20170311011848",
    "node": "registry:env/node#0.10.0+20170213133316"
  }
}
```

Furthermore, I read somewhere that Typings is deprecated, but I can't find a replacement for it so that doesn't really do me any good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use angular-cli to generate angular 4 project. Here is the link: https://cli.angular.io/

Steps that you need to follow:

1. Install the Angular CLI:

> ```
> npm install -g @angular/cli
> ```

2. Generating and serving an Angular project :

> ```
> ng new my-project
> cd my-project
> ng serve
> ```

3. open http://localhost:4200/  in your browser

Comment: I didn't know that this was even an option. Thanks! I will try and put my files in this new project and see if it works.